# Google Analytic's / Duplicate entries / Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, duplicates, google-tag-manager

We have Google Analytics on our site. This site also uses Google Tag Manager (unsure whether this is causing the issue or not).

The issue is that within Google Developer on the Network tab it looks like Google Analytics is being called three times, therefore messing up the actual analytics side.

[image]

I have searched the web for this issue but most put it down to the page refreshes etc. This is not the case with ours. This happens when it is first loaded.

Each URL is different slightly. I looked through the site code hoping to find duplicate data (script for Google Analytics), sadly I haven’t. Neither have a found duplication when I 'View Source'.

At this moment in time I am puzzled as to why this is happening.

I have noted the parameters are slightly different between the three, I am thinking this is why it looks like its being called three times, why would it do this?

[image]

- DP: Document location URL (The call which doesn't contain GTM, contains this)
- GTM: Google Tag Manager (Two of the three
  have this in the third doesn't)
- CD1: ? (The call which doesn't contain GTM, contains this)
- Z: Cache

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Clare

Comment: It seems, as you include the ec.js plugin, that you are using enhanced E-Commerce. This might cause additionals calls to Google Analytics if you do product list tracking or something.  You should install the Google Analytics Debugger extension (if you use Chrome) or manually inspect the  calls to GA to see what the hit type is for each call (obviously there should be only one "pageview" call, but other hit types on the same page are okay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most definitely possible that GA and GTM both sending page views. If you are using GTM then you should remove ALL GA code from your pages as GTM replaces all GA.